# Cosine Distance > 1 in scipy

Tags: python, distance, cosine-distance

I am working on a recommendation engine, and I have chosen to use SciPy's cosine distance as a way of comparing items.

I have two vectors:

```
a = [2.7654870801855078, 0.35995355443076027, 0.016221679989074141, -0.012664358453398751, 0.0036888812311235068]
```

and

```
b = [-6.2588482809118942, -0.88952297609194686, 0.017336984676103874, -0.0054928004763216964, 0.011122959185936367]
```

Running the following code will produce an output of ~1.999:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
print(distance.cosine(a,b))
```

Is there something wrong with my input values? Anyone know why I am getting a result of >1?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The cosine distance formula is:

[image]

And the formula used by the `cosine` function of the `spatial` class of scipy is:

[image]

So, the actual cosine similarity metric is: -0.9998.

So, it signifies complete dissimilarity.