# Calculating KL Divergence in Python

Tags: python, clustering, scikit-learn

I am rather new to this and can't say I have a complete understanding of the theoretical concepts behind this. I am trying to calculate the KL Divergence between several lists of points in Python. I am using [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mutual_info_score.html) to try and do this. The problem that I'm running into is that the value returned is the same for any 2 lists of numbers (its 1.3862943611198906). I have a feeling that I'm making some sort of theoretical mistake here but can't spot it.

```
values1 = [1.346112,1.337432,1.246655]
values2 = [1.033836,1.082015,1.117323]
metrics.mutual_info_score(values1,values2)
```

That is an example of what I'm running - just that I'm getting the same output for any 2 input. Any advice/help would be appreciated!

Comment: By KL, do you mean Kullback-Leibler divergence?

Comment: Yes, exactly that!

Comment: By running `sklearn.metrics.mutual_info_score([1.346112,1.337432,1.246655], [1.033836,1.082015,1.117323])`, I get the value `1.0986122886681096`.

Comment: Sorry, i was using values1 as [1, 1.346112,1.337432,1.246655] and values2 as values2 as [1,1.033836,1.082015,1.117323] and hence the difference value.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

First of all, `sklearn.metrics.mutual_info_score` implements *mutual information* for evaluating clustering results, not *pure* Kullback-Leibler divergence!

> This is equal to the Kullback-Leibler divergence of the joint distribution with the product distribution of the marginals.

KL divergence (and any other such measure) expects the input data to **have a sum of 1**. Otherwise, they are *not* proper **probability distributions**. If your data does not have a sum of 1, most likely it is usually not proper to use KL divergence! (In some cases, it may be admissible to have a sum of less than 1, e.g. in the case of missing data.)

Also note that it is common to use base 2 logarithms. This only yields a constant scaling factor in difference, but base 2 logarithms are easier to interpret and have a more intuitive scale (0 to 1 instead of 0 to log2=0.69314..., measuring the information in bits instead of nats).

```
> sklearn.metrics.mutual_info_score([0,1],[1,0])
0.69314718055994529
```

as we can clearly see, the MI result of sklearn is scaled using natural logarithms instead of log2. This is an unfortunate choice, as explained above.

Kullback-Leibler divergence is fragile, unfortunately. On above example it is not well-defined: `KL([0,1],[1,0])` causes a division by zero, and tends to infinity. It is also *asymmetric*.

Comment: Note that when `scipy.stats.entropy` is used, it will normalize the probabilities to one. From the docs (http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.stats.entropy.html): "This routine will normalize pk and qk if they don’t sum to 1."

Answer (score 25):

Scipy's [entropy function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.entropy.html) will calculate KL divergence if feed two vectors p and q, each representing a probability distribution. If the two vectors aren't pdfs, it will normalize then first.

Mutual information is [related to, but not the same](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information) as KL Divergence.

"This weighted mutual information is a form of weighted KL-Divergence, which is known to take negative values for some inputs, and there are examples where the weighted mutual information also takes negative values"

Answer (score 15):

I'm not sure with the scikit-learn implementation, but here is a quick implementation of the KL divergence in Python:

```
import numpy as np

def KL(a, b):
    a = np.asarray(a, dtype=np.float)
    b = np.asarray(b, dtype=np.float)

    return np.sum(np.where(a != 0, a * np.log(a / b), 0))


values1 = [1.346112,1.337432,1.246655]
values2 = [1.033836,1.082015,1.117323]

print KL(values1, values2)
```

Output:  `0.775279624079`

There might be [conflict of implementation](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/8429/11097) in some libraries, so make sure you read their docs before using.

Comment: I tried this too but this was returning negative values which, I think, is not a valid value. A little bit of research then got me to this result http://mathoverflow.net/questions/43849/how-to-ensure-the-non-negativity-of-kullback-leibler-divergence-kld-metric-rela which talks about how the input has to be a probability distribution. Guess that is where I made my mistake.

Comment: @Nanda  Thanks for the link. Mine returns `0.775279624079` for your inputs and the sklearn metrics return `1.3862943611198906`.  Confused still!   But, seems like including those value checks according to the qn, into the script should do :)

Comment: I know what you mean! I have tried 3 different functions to get 3 different values with the only thing common between them being that the result didn't "feel" right. The input values is definitely a logical error so changing my approach altogether!

Comment: @Nanda  Ahh, that's clear now :)  Thanks for explaining

Answer (score 4):

This trick avoids conditional code and may therefore provide better performance.

```
import numpy as np

def KL(P,Q):
""" Epsilon is used here to avoid conditional code for
checking that neither P nor Q is equal to 0. """
     epsilon = 0.00001

     # You may want to instead make copies to avoid changing the np arrays.
     P = P+epsilon
     Q = Q+epsilon

     divergence = np.sum(P*np.log(P/Q))
     return divergence

# Should be normalized though
values1 = np.asarray([1.346112,1.337432,1.246655])
values2 = np.asarray([1.033836,1.082015,1.117323])

# Note slight difference in the final result compared to Dawny33
print KL(values1, values2) # 0.775278939433
```

Comment: Nice trick! I'd be interested to see how this compares with the other solution on a time benchmark.

Answer (score 2):

Kullback-Leibler divergence is basically the sum of the [relative entropy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.rel_entr.html) of two probabilities:

```
vec = scipy.special.rel_entr(p, q)    
kl_div = np.sum(vec)
```

As mentioned before, just make sure p and q are probability distributions (sum up to 1). You can always normalize them before:

```
p /= np.sum(p)
```

Relative entropy is defined as p*log(p/q), so where q==0, the result is inf.
You can mask those values using:

```
vec = np.ma.masked_invalid(vec).compressed()
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the three following samples from a distribution(s).

```
values1 = np.asarray([1.3,1.3,1.2])
values2 = np.asarray([1.0,1.1,1.1])
values3 = np.array([1.8,0.7,1.7])
```

Clearly, values1 and values2 are closer, so we expect the measure of `surprise` or entropy, to be lower when compared to values3.

```
from scipy.stats import entropy
print("\nIndividual Entropy\n")
print(entropy(values1))
print(entropy(values2))
print(entropy(values3))

print("\nPairwise Kullback Leibler divergence\n")
print(entropy(values1, qk=values2))
print(entropy(values1, qk=values3))
print(entropy(values2, qk=values3))
```

We see the following output:

```
Individual Entropy

1.097913446793334
1.0976250611902076
1.0278436769863724 #<--- this one had the lowest, but doesn't mean much.

Pairwise Kullback Leibler divergence

0.002533297351606588
0.09053972625203921 #<-- makes sense
0.09397968199352116 #<-- makes sense
```

We see this makes sense because the values between values1 and values3 and values 2 and values 3 are simply more drastic in change than values1 to values 2. This is my validation to understanding KL-D and the packages that can be leveraged for it.